# How can I test a JBossMQ JMS Queue with JMeter

Tags: jboss, jms, jmeter, jbossmq

I'd like to use JMeter test that I can send a message to a JBossMQ (JBoss 4.2.3 JMS Queue). If I get that far then I will be able to build some load and other tests.

JBoss is pretty much straight out of the box and is a server called *servername*. Since there are some queues set up by default, lets use Queue A which according to ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/deploy/jms/jbossmq-destinations-service.xml has the values

```
 <mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue"
         name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=A">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager</depends>
 </mbean>
```

JMeter wants to know:

- QueueConnectionFactory
- JNDIname Request queue
- any JMS properties
- any JNDI properties
- a provider URL

can you please help me fill in the boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the desired values from the JBoss MQ client examples: http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/QueueExample.